# Partial View in mvc4 Control Resuability

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have 2 Pages, 'Login' and 'Register'.

On the Register page I have 4 controls: Username, Password, Confirm Password, Email.
On the Login page I have Username and Password controls.

If I put register.cshtml page in shared, when I call the login page, my idea is to have only username and password controls on the Login page to be called from register.cshtml by hiding the Confirm password and Email controls.

Can you suggest me how can I do this, I just started my training in MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we don't call them controls in asp.net mvc, they are html elements or you can call them fields.

If you want to share those fields among multiple pages you can create a partial view and put those fields there and use `@RenderPartial("_UsernameAndPasswordFields")` to render it in both of your pages.

However I don't think if it is a good idea to create a partial for just those two fields it would be cleaner to just make two separate pages with their own fields.